# Application of theorem on gluing vectors in lattice theory to $E_8$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, integer-lattices

I'm currently learning about gluing vectors in lattice theory, mainly from *The (Sensual) Quadratic Form* by Conway & Fung, and *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups* by Conway & Sloane. In the latter, in page 100, there is a theorem which states

> **Theorem 1:** *If a unimodular lattice $L$ is formed by gluing together two lattices $L_1$ and $L_2$ in such a way that there is no
>   self-glue, i.e., if*
>
> $$L_1 = (L_1 \otimes \mathbb{R}) \cap L, ~~ L_2 = (L_2 \otimes
>  \mathbb{R}) \cap L,$$
>
> *then the dual quotients $L_1^*/L_1$ and $L_2^*/L_2$* are isomorphic groups.

In working with the $E_8$ lattice, one finds rank 8 sublattices by using the extended diagram algorithm, getting the eight lattices

$$A_8,~A_1A_2A_5,~A_4^2,~D_5A_3,~E_6A_2,~E_7A_1,~A_1A_7,~D_8$$

Of these, four are products of two lattices and can be extended to $E_8$ again by including a glue vector corresponding to the simple root which was deleted in the extended diagram algorithm. Now, I find that **Theorem 1** holds in the cases
$$E_7A_1, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ E_7^*/E_7 \simeq A_1^*/A_1 \simeq \mathbb
Z_2,$$
$$E_6A_2, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ E_6^*/E_6 \simeq A_2^*/A_2 \simeq \mathbb
Z_3,$$
$$D_5A_3, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ D_5^*/D_5 \simeq A_3^*/A_3 \simeq \mathbb
Z_4.$$

However, for the case $A_1A_7$ the dual quotients are $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_8$, which are obviously not isomorphic. Given that the glue vector required for extending $A_1A_7 \to E_8$ is not orthogonal to either of these sublattices, **Theorem 1** should hold.

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Incidentally, the lattices $A_1A_2$ and $A_5$ have isomorphic dual quotients $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_6$. Does this mean anything?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that **Theorem 1** does not hold for the sublattice $A_1\oplus A_7$ is that $A_7$ *does have a self-glue* in $E_8$.

Let us define the $E_8$ lattice as the set of vectors $v = (v_1,...,v_8)$ such that all $v_i$'s are simultaneously integer or half-integer, and $\sum_{i = 1}^8 v_i \in 2 \mathbb Z$, as usual.

An embedding of $A_1\oplus A_7$ into $E_8$ is given by the basis vectors

$$ A_1: (\tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12) $$

and

$$A_7: (1,-1,0,...,0), (0,1,-1,0,...,0),...,(0,...,0,1,-1). $$

Now, the real span of this particular $A_7$ is the set of points $\{x = (x_1,...,x_8) | \sum_{i = 1}^8 x_i = 0\}$, which contains in particular the vector $v = (\tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, \tfrac12, -\tfrac12, -\tfrac12, -\tfrac12, -\tfrac12)$. This vector is a self-glue for $A_7$, extending it to $E_7$, and we recover the case $A_1 \oplus E_7 \subset E_8$, which satisfies **Theorem 1**.

In the theory of lattices we would equivalently say that $A_7$ is not *primitively embedded* into $E_8$.

The lattices $A_1 \oplus A_2$ and $A_5$ can be shown to be primitively embedded in $E_8$ such that they are mutually orthogonal, hence they satisfy **Theorem 1**.